# Custom slide titles in beamer

Tags: beamer, header-footer, positioning

My slides have a particular PDF background and I would like to force slide-titles to appear in a particular place on each slide without a blue box underneath them. I want the `\frametitle{}` command to place my title in white text, flush right, at the top right of my slide with no surrounding box or anything. Is this possible? More generally, is it possible to get LaTeX/`beamer` to draw textboxes (with line/fill options) in specific places on slides?

Comment: Is there a particular theme you'd want to start from? Are you using any headlines or similar features?

Comment: I'm just using the default theme.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Since I don't have your background, I'm opting for red text instead of white. Depending on what you really want, you may want to adjust the font and right margin.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\setbeamersize{text margin right=0pt} % Beamer manual, section 8.3
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=red} % Beamer manual, section 16.3
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{series=\bfseries}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}
{
\hfill\insertframetitle
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{This is the frame title}
Here's some more content. Here's some more content. Here's some more content.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```