# beamer: frame without decorations, with custom margin

Tags: beamer, margins

I use `\begin{frame}[plain]` to have a frame without decorations. The content (inside `columns` environment) seems to horizontally still respecting the old margins (with Warsaw, gap on the left), although vertically, the whole space is taken as it should be. Beamer manual says that `plain` only suppresses decorations, but does not mention it changing geometry.

Is there a straightforward way to have empty frame, with some user-defined margins?

**EDIT:** this is what I get with the following; text on the second slide is not left.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\begin{document}
\section{foo}
\begin{frame}[t]
    Text
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[plain,t]
    Text
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT 2:**

The solutions suggested by @MarcoDaniel does not restore the margin correctly unfortunately (without `\restoregeometry`, the slide decoration starts on the left correctly, but the block goes over it just like on the screenshot). Enclosing the change in `\bgroup...\egroup` does not help:

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The bounty has already been awarded, but here's the `beamer` way:

`beamer` uses six horizontal lengths:

- `\beamer@leftsidebar` and `\beamer@rightsidebar` store
  the (horizontal) sizes of the side bars.
- `\beamer@leftmargin` and `\beamer@rightmargin` store the
  distance between sidebar and text.
- The macros `\Gm@lmargin` and `\Gm@rmargin` store the distance from the
  edge of the paper to the edge of the text.

Thus the sum `\beamer@leftsidebar` and `\beamer@leftmargin` is exactly `\Gm@lmargin`.

Thus, if you wish to put some text right next to the left edge of paper with the proper separation, you need a horizontal skip equal to  `\beamer@leftsidebar` to get there.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength\leftsidebar
\newlength\rightsidebar
\makeatletter
\setlength\leftsidebar{\beamer@leftsidebar}
\setlength\rightsidebar{\beamer@rightsidebar}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
\lipsum[4]
\end{frame}

\hoffset=-\leftsidebar
\begin{frame}[plain,t]
\lipsum[4]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I found I had to use `-0.5\leftsidebar` to get it to work

Comment: You might want to check [my answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/334751/93613) to [this related post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/142569/93613), where I compile stuff from different answers and end up with even less `beamer`-hacking than in this answer.

Comment: There is a bug in this approach. Please, put there a new textual content after removing the left bar. There is no stopper at the end. How to do it? - - I think you need `\hoffset=0in % restore left margin`.

Answer (score 13):

One way to do this is to use the `changemargin` environment from [UK List of
TeX FAQ](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-chngmargonfly):

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berkeley}

\newenvironment{changemargin}[2]{%
  \begin{list}{}{%
    \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{#1}%
    \setlength{\rightmargin}{#2}%
    \setlength{\listparindent}{\parindent}%
    \setlength{\itemindent}{\parindent}%
    \setlength{\parsep}{\parskip}%
  }%
  \item[]}{\end{list}} 

\begin{document}
\section{foo}
\begin{frame}[t]
    Text
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[plain,t]
\begin{changemargin}{-2cm}{0cm} 
    Text
\end{changemargin}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

A simple solution is change the `\hoffset`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\begin{document}
\section{foo}

\begin{frame}[t]
    Text
\end{frame}

\hoffset=-.8in % no left margin

\begin{frame}[plain,t]
    Text 
\end{frame}

\hoffset=0in % restore left margin

\begin{frame}[t]
    Text 
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

**Edit**

*Determine automatically the right `\hoffset`*

To remove the left margin (completely, not as in the MWE)  you can add this to the preamble:

```
\usepackage{calc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/calc
\newlength{\noleftmargin}
\setlength{\noleftmargin}{-1in-\oddsidemargin}%
```

And then, before of the plain frame, use:

```
 \hoffset=\noleftmargin
```

*Explanation*

The left margin of a Beamer presentation is always `1 inch` plus the lengths `\hoffset` and `\oddsidemargin`.

In the default theme, as well as in Berkeley or Warsaw you can see that the default `\hoffset` is `0pt` and `\oddsidemargin` is a negative value. You always can check this value with `\the\oddsidemargin`.

How I can one be sure that there are exactly 1 inch plus `\hoffset` plus `\oddsidemargin`? Use the package `layout`:

[image: MWE2]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\usepackage{layout}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
The \texttt{\textbackslash hoffset} is now \the\hoffset\\
The \texttt{\textbackslash oddsidemargin} is now \the\oddsidemargin
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[plain]
\vspace{-1.5cm}\hspace{1cm}\vbox{% only to move a little the scheme  
\layout
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

So, in the first MWE, as the default `\oddsidemargin` was `-13pt` (`-.18in`), still remain - roughly -  `0.8 inches` of left margin.

Therefore, you can  remove completely the left margin changing accordingly one or two of these lengths. For example, without the package `calc` and nothing special in the preamble , you can also remove the left margin with:

```
\oddsidemargin=0pt
\hoffset=-1in
```

But this way you need to restore two values to return to the defaults.

Comment: This solution is very simple :-). If you can tell me a way to automatically determine the `-.8in` you get the bounty.

Comment: In my opinion, the bounty is well deserved :-). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

The class `beamer` loads the package `geometry` by default. The package geometry provides the command `\newgeometry` which allows to change the page settings inside the document.

Here an example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\begin{document}
\section{foo}
\begin{frame}[t]

Text
\end{frame}

\newgeometry{margin=1cm}
\begin{frame}[plain,t]

Text
\end{frame}
\restoregeometry
\begin{frame}[plain,t]

Text
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I double-checked, the theme was Berekeley, and posted a screen into the quietion itself.

Comment: Oh crap, the geometry does not get restored properly :-| I put screenshot of the question edit...

Comment: What @eudoxos says: the geometry does not get reset.

Comment: @Ingo I've provided another answer below using the native `beamer` lengths. I don't care about the bounty, though (and you've already awarded it), but you might be interested in knowing the "proper" lengths that `beamer` uses in a frame.

Answer (score 1):

Related to [this earlier question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33900/custom-slide-titles-in-beamer):

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=1ex} % Beamer manual, section 8.3
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[plain,t]
Here's some more content. Here's some more content. Here's some more content.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: that solution doesn't work inside `\begin{document}`. The command uses `\geometry`. You can use `\newgeometry` instead.

Comment: What doesn't work inside `\begin{document}`? Not following.

Comment: The command `\setbeamersize` works only in the preamble. So you can manipulation a single frame with this command.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: confirming that `{ \newgeometry{margin=1cm}\begin{frame}[plain] ... \end{frame} }` works. Can you write it as answer so that it is visible and I can accept it? Thanks!

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: I did :-)