# How can I increase the width of the document?

Tags: beamer, margins

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [beamer: frame without decorations, with custom margin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34367/beamer-frame-without-decorations-with-custom-margin)

I want increase the width of the document. I have to put four images in one slide. Two in one row each, because of which the images are coming small. How to go about it?

Have used the following code to display images:

```
\begin{frame}[plain]
\vcenteredhbox{\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=5cm,keepaspectratio]{pc3.jpg}}
\vcenteredhbox{\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=5cm,keepaspectratio]{pc4.png}}
 \end{frame}
```

Comment: That looks wierd; is it a squared image? Btw. you can use the [geometry package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/geometry/) to change the page layout.

Comment: Please provide us with a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/15925) so we can see which beamer style you are using etc.  If this is included in a `frame`, one possibility would be to write `\begin{frame][plain]` to get as much space as possible.

Comment: What you provide does not compile on a standard system; `\vcenteredhbox` is not defined by `beamer`.   Does [Peter Grill's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34373/15925) solve your problem?