# Full width image in beamer?

Tags: beamer, margins, geometry

I have a beamer presentation with a custom style which creates a red bar along the bottom of each slide. When I change the geometry and then revert it with restoregeometry, the red bar is now shifted to the right.  The aim is just to have the picture full width.

```
\documentclass{beamer}   
\mode<presentation>
 {
\usetheme{myslides}
 }

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{}

\begin{center}
\huge Introduction?
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\newgeometry{margin=0pt}

\begin{frame}[fragile, plain]
\frametitle{}
\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth, width=\paperwidth]{picture}
\end{frame}

\restoregeometry
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{}
\begin{center}
\huge Next slide?
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

How can I restore back to exactly the state it was in before the newgeometry command?

My question seems related to [beamer: frame without decorations, with custom margin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34367/beamer-frame-without-decorations-with-custom-margin) as well where there is a similar problem with \restoregeometry in one of the answers.

Comment: Why don't you make the changes local, as in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/3927/28346)?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Without having access to your beamer theme nor to the image, it is difficult to test. But if you know the size of your margins the following (dirty but simple) solution might work.

```
\vspace*{-6.5mm}    
\begin{frame}[plain]
    \hspace*{-19mm}
    \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{picture}
\end{frame}
```

(to be used without any geometry resetting commands)

---

Or without manually fiddling around with the size of the margins:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\newlength\beamerleftmargin
\setlength\beamerleftmargin{\Gm@lmargin}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
     
\begin{frame}[plain]
    \hspace*{-\beamerleftmargin}%
    \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{example-image}
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I had to play with the exact size for \hspace*{-19mm} but with -7mm it worked perfectly.

Comment: I've been struggling with this for a long time now, thanks for `\Gm@lmargin`.

Comment: The answer below by Benjamin, to me, seems much more useful. If you end up here you might want to check that answer as well although it has by far less points.

Comment: @Nobody-Knows-I-am-a-Dog Sure, if you want to mess up all following frames...

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz How come? Would one not restrict the changes to a local scope? That way it should work. Or undoing the change explicitly if you want.

Comment: @Nobody-Knows-I-am-a-Dog No, newgeometry won't obey the group. Try https://pastebin.com/xqV3FWbV

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz For me it does obey the group, see https://pastebin.com/hw4RG4ZY. The problem with your pastebin might be that you are setting a template inside of the group - maybe this exports some value in some way.

Comment: @Nobody-Knows-I-am-a-Dog No it does not. You just don't see the problem without a footline

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz The footline is a completely different story. I agree this is a problem and I am currently trying to fix that. But it has nothing to do with newgeometry not obeying the group. At least it does obey the group in my pastebin.

Comment: @Nobody-Knows-I-am-a-Dog If it would obey the group, the footline would not be missing on the following frames

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz The problem is with footline and the way beamer calculates it I do not think newgeometry is so severely broken that it obeys groups only in some parameters.We probably mean the same but use different word to describe it. To me, this is the source of disagreement.

Comment: @Nobody-Knows-I-am-a-Dog The way beamer calculates the height of a static element is not the problem, the users messing with the geometry are the problem

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz The design decision of doing so statically is the problem. In my opinion. Users changing the geometry have a reason to do so. Beamer fails to implement this.

Comment: @Nobody-Knows-I-am-a-Dog Beamer does not fail to implement this, there are many build in ways to temporarily change the margin size. If you insist to change them in another way, that's your problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115245/discussion-between-nobody-knows-i-am-a-dog-and-samcarter-is-at-topanswers-xyz).

Answer (score 14):

A `plain` frame with a `background` image can be locally applied without need for changing and restoring geometry changes

```
\documentclass{beamer}   
\mode<presentation>
 {
\usetheme{Berkeley} %<-- We don't have `myslides` theme
 }

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{}

\begin{center}
\huge Introduction?
\end{center}
\end{frame}

{%<--- Start local changes
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{example-image}}
\begin{frame}[plain]
\end{frame}
}%<---- Finish local changes

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{}
\begin{center}
\huge Next slide?
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

A very simple solution using `tikz`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node[at=(current page.center)] {
            \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth, height=\paperheight]{example-image}
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[has to be compiled two times to get the coordinates right]

Comment: It even works with rmarkdown :-)

Comment: @OttToomet Good to hear!

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT:** I should have tested this in more detail before posting. It seems that the following frames have their geometry/layout modified... So please be aware that there might be some issues.

After looking at different answers and comments from different questions around this problem of beamer still having a left margin in plain frames, let me post the solution I just found, to get a **really empty plain frame**, no margins etc. in an easy automated generic way. In such a frame, one can do as wished, for example put a graphic that exactly takes the whole width of the frame, or center it with exactly the same left and right spaces, without having to cheat with horizontal offsets or whatever.

The problem I had was that `\setbeamersize{text margin left=0pt}` or the likes can't be used in a local way, it has to be in the preamble, it can't be in the body and also not in command or environment definitions.

The solution was to use `\newgeometry`, as used in the OPs question, from the `geometry` package, loaded by `beamer`, and restrain it locally as suggested in the comment above. And it needs no fancy stuff, no ad hoc lengths, etc.

It seems that it hasn't been posted like I am about to do, and I think it could be interesting to a wide audience (I looked long before finding it). And the only other answer I know of that needs no ad hoc ajustments, namely [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/198224/93613), uses little more `beamer`-hacking knowledge.

Solution for one isolated frame:

```
{\newgeometry{margin=0pt} %locally set margins to zero
 \setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[default] %not too sure, but may be needed if you have a background image
 \begin{frame}[plain]
 %frame content  that can really fill the whole page
 \end{frame}
}
```

And if you need this on a regular basis, define it as a new environment, e.g. `emptyframe`, in the preamble:

```
\newenvironment{emptyframe}
{
 % not too sure, but may be needed if you have a background image
 % that should not appear on this kind of frame:
 \setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[default] 
 % locally set margins to zero: (notice the use of \bgroup ... \egroup
 % to limit the scope of the geometry restriction
 % where curly brackets {} aren't possible)
 \bgroup \newgeometry{margin=0cm} 
 \begin{frame}[plain]
}
{
 \end{frame}
 \egroup
}
```

After that, in the body of the document, use it alternatively to a `frame` environment:

```
\begin{emptyframe}
% frame content that can really fill the whole page
\end{emptyframe}
```

Note 1: you might also need to turn off navigation symbols. To this effect, add `\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}` next to `\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[default]`.

Note 2: this solution is not limited to getting empty frames, it is (I think, didn't test) customizable up to the limits of `\newgeometry`.

Comment: This is awesome; it's by far one of the easiest ways to insert figures in beamer with `\newcommand`, without worrying about size or placement.

Comment: There is a missing backslash before `newgeometry` in the isolated frame example.