# Removing black spaces of embedded video in beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, graphics, multimedia

I am experiences some issues when including videos in my beamer presentation. Here is my frame,

```
\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
\movie[width=6cm,height=4.5cm]{}{videos/test.avi}
\end{frame}
```

The problem occurs when I set the width and the height of the video. When I enter Presentation-mode of my PDF-viewer, black spaces occur at the sides of the video.

Is there a way to completely get rid of these?

I tried forcing the background color to white before the frame (`\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=white}`), but that didn't solve the issue.

---

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{multimedia}


\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{gensymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame 1}
\movie[poster,autostart,width=6cm,height=4.5cm,repeat=true]{}{rho.avi}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The video is here: https://ufile.io/fb2de

---

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Maybe have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/143102/36296, this shows how to include full width images. But if your video has another aspect ratio then the presentation, some margins are inevitable.

Comment: @samcarter Is it possible to override the margins, maybe by setting the background color or some other "dirty" trick?

Comment: Can you make a compilable MWE that can reproduce your situation. Maybe with some dummy video we can access?

Comment: @samcarter added a mwe with a video. when I enter presentation-mode with my pdf-viewer, black margins occur.

Comment: @samcarter I see black margins around the video in addition to the left/right margins caused by the fullscreen view. You do not see these?

Comment: This kind of animation could as well be embedded using the `animate` package, if you have the files of  the single frames (preferably as original vector graphics) available.

Comment: @samcarter Added a screenshot. I use Okular on Debian

Comment: @BillyJean I cannot test with okular, but maybe try with `borderwidth=0pt` in the options of the movie.

Comment: @samcarter Thanks for the suggestion, I tried it out - it doesn't remove the margin though. It is weird, because the margins only appear in Presentation-mode - when it is "normal", they don't appear.

Comment: You may try a 16:9 ratio: `\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}`.

Comment: @PaulGaborit I tried, the margin still occurs

Comment: @BillyJean The ratio of your screen is 16:9 and the ratio of your video is 4:3...

Comment: @PaulGaborit That only works for the particular video. Say I have many videos in the beamer of different size, is there a way to fix it in that case? E.g., if I can merely specify the height, then the width is chosen automatically to match that of the video?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem on windows with acrobat viewer. But it looks like a pdf-viewer artifact. Instead of trying to hide the margins you could add a black frame or background around the movie to make them look intentional.

Comment: @BillyJean Can you please test something (I don't see these black margins, so I cannot test myself)? What happens if one draws a white frame around the boarder? `\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{multimedia}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

{
\setbeamertemplate{logo}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
 \draw[yellow, line width=10pt] (-11.7,2.2) rectangle (-5.7,6.6);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{frame}{Frame 1}
\movie[poster,autostart,width=6cm,height=4.5cm,repeat=true]{}{rho.avi}
\end{frame}
}
\end{document}`

Comment: @samcarter They still appear, they are now inside the yellow frame

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [**`media9`**](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/media9) package instead of **`multimedia`** (comes with beamer), which requires to convert your video to **.mp4** first (e.g. [here](https://convertio.co/de/avi-mp4/) or wherever). It's worth the effort as `media9` allows to include the video physically in the PDF, means you don't need to carry around the actual video file and you're not dependent on any codecs available on the target PC (which would be the case with an external **.avi** file and `multimedia`).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{media9}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{gensymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame 1}
    \includemedia[
          width=6cm,height=4.5cm,
          activate=pageopen,        
          keepaspectratio,          % optionally useful
          transparent,              % optionally useful
          playbutton=plain,
          addresource=rho.mp4,
          flashvars={
              source=rho.mp4 
             &autoPlay=true
             &loop=true}
        ]{}{VPlayer.swf}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In case the player's  and the video's aspect ratios don't match exactly (due to resampling of the video while viewing) it is worthwhile adding option `transparent`. It makes the player's background transparent and further reduces the occurrence of black lines around the video

Comment: Thanks. I tried out your example with `rho.mp4`, but in the PDF nothing plays - it only shows a grey bar with a play-triangle inside it. Nothing happens though when I push it. Is the part `VPlayer.swf` correct?

Comment: @BillyJean : Do you use A-Reader (or Foxit or PDF-XChange) for viewing the PDF?

Comment: @AlexG I tried with both Okular and Foxit (on Debian)

Comment: @BillyJean : Okular doesn't support the embedding method of `media9`. And only the Windows version of Foxit works.

Comment: @AlexG I see, thanks. Wow, I have bad luck all the way with this...

Comment: @BillyJean : Installing and running A-Reader and FlashPlayer in Wine under Linux could be an option for you.

Comment: @BillyJean I'm sorry, but I didn't knew there would be issues with other pdf readers. Unfortunately I can't provide another solution for them.